# Update comment meta for all comments of specific post

Tags: comments, comment-meta

Questions says it pretty much ... Is it possible to change the comment meta for all comments of a specific post?

I know it probably works like this:

```
$comments = get_comments( array(

    'post_id' => $post->ID,

) );

foreach( $comments as $comment ) {

    update_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'accepted', '0' );

}
```

But is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: what does it mean "elegant"?

Comment: I could imagine this solution is not very performant with many comments?

Comment: @Grandy can you explain more about what specifically you are trying to do, where you are trying to accomplish it, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: sure, so there is a question of why does it matter. If you going to run it once a year, performances will not matter much and maintenability might be much more important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will be very slow if there are N no of comments. Use following approach for much faster execution.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = '
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( comment_ID ) AS ids
    FROM  `wp_comments` 
    WHERE comment_post_ID =  '.$POST_ID;

    $ids = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

if(isset($ids[0]['ids']) && $ids[0]['ids'] != ''){
    $wpdb->query('
        UPDATE wp_commentmeta 
        SET meta_value = 0 
        WHERE comment_id IN ('.$ids[0]['ids'].') 
        AND meta_key = "accepted"
    ');
}
```

**P.S** : Haven't tested the code.

Comment: Worked fine, thank you. Consider using $wpdb->comments and $wpdb->commentmeta just if anyone want to copy this ;) I didn't tested the actuall speed benefit against my solution but im pretty sure this is faster (because SQL pretty directly).